# Resize video in ion-card-content

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a Ionic grid in which I have a list of videos :

```
  <ion-grid fixed>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="4"
               size-xs="12"
               size-sm="6"
               size-md="4"
               size-lg="3"
               *ngFor="let url of allItems | async">
        <ion-card>
          <ion-card-content>
            <video width="300" height="300"  autoplay controls>
              <source src="{{url}}" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="{{url}}" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

The different sizes are used to adapt the grid according to the screen used. However, I would like to have the size of the videos as big as the card. Or in case the card is bigger than the video size, don't resize the video but have it placed in the middle of the card.
Now I have this situation using width and height 300:
[image]

I would like the video to be as big as the card, but for now it is smaller. If I try to remove these two dimensions, the card explodes, that is, it comes out gigantic. The same happens if I set widht:100% in the css . Lastly to center the video I tried this, but it doesn't work:
.css:

```
ion-card-content {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<ion-grid fixed>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col size="4" size-xs="12" size-sm="6" size-md="4" size-lg="3" *ngFor="let url of allItems | async">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <video width="300" height="300" autoplay controls>
              <source src="{{url}}" type="video/mp4">
              <source src="{{url}}" type="video/ogg">
            </video>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: I've taken your code and tried to create a runnable Snippet for inclusion with the question, so that we can better see what's going on and offer practicable suggestions. Would you be able to update the JavaScript and CSS to better reproduce the issue in the Snippet (using the 'JavaScript' (lower-left) and 'CSS' (upper-right) panels)?

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas, in what sense I have to modify javascript?

Comment: I assume by supplying the data that the Angular framework expects? I've never worked with Angular before, so I honestly don't know how to help advise on that. Effectively it's to make the demo work the same here as it does in your dev environment but with the minimum required to reproduce the problematic part. See the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines for advice and guidance. I'm sorry I can't be more useful in this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-card {
position:relative;width:100%;}
ion-card-content {
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
margin:auto;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @zrelli, non funziona. Doesn't work. Ion-cards are no longer shown

Comment: Try to add a height and width to ion card.